# What's the best way to include code samples in a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint

Thank you in advance to anyone who can move this question to a better suited stack exchange site.

I've looked through the various stack exchange options but I'm unsure where to post this question. I'm putting together an hour long C# intro for some Visual Basic programmers.

I'd like to include some code samples but I'd rather not have to include a bunch of screen shots of code I'd rather have some properly color coded text.

Does anyone else have experience with this sort of thing?

Comment: http://superuser.com seems more adapted.

Comment: If this gets closed here I'll delete the question and move it there.

Comment: When I cut/paste code into Word, colorization is copied with it. That doesn't work in PowerPoint?

Comment: Another good option for this question might be /*Programmers*/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post may be what you're looking for: http://www.fauskes.net/nb/syntaxms/

Comment: Will Notepad++ do the same thing?

Comment: Ok ... interesting ... +1 for scintilla ... MS Word will keep colorization from VS, but PowerPoint will not ... inconsistency sucks

Comment: PowerPoint will but only if you tell it to "Keep source formatting" when pasting.